# Authlogic OpenID: Fetching E-Mail from Provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic-oid, openid-selector

This is a really weird problem: I have set up the [authlogic_openid_selector_example app](http://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example). When i register, the email id is not returned by the openid provider the first time. But if i delete the account and register again, the email id is returned.  How do i fix this problem? I have hosted my version of the app here: http://pingauthtest.heroku.com/

I looked at my development log and the first time the provider doesn't return the `openid.ext1.value.ext0` which contains the email id. This is returned the second time only after having deleted the account first.

**Edit**: Some extra info for debugging:

```
THIS IS WHEN IT REGISTERS:



  OpenIdAuthentication::Association Load (5.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "open_id_authentication_associations" WHERE ("open_id_authentication_associations"."server_url" = E'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud') 
Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication AOQobUde_9BUnQsk91rb_Sf9tguJ-S7Gpkwahc-nvDGDYAC8nphisNqu
Redirected to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?
openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUde_9BUnQsk91rb_Sf9tguJ-S7Gpkwahc-nvDGDYAC8nphisNqu

&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request
&openid.ax.required=ext0
&openid.ax.type.ext0=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail
&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0
&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1
&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Faccount%3Ffor_model%3D1%26_method%3Dpost%26open_id_complete%3D1
&openid.sreg.required=email
Completed in 3574ms (DB: 14) | 302 Found [http://localhost/account]
```

---

```
THIS IS WHEN IT USES SESSIONS:


 OpenIdAuthentication::Association Load (5.3ms)   SELECT * FROM "open_id_authentication_associations" WHERE ("open_id_authentication_associations"."server_url" = E'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud') 
Generated checkid_setup request to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud with assocication AOQobUde_9BUnQsk91rb_Sf9tguJ-S7Gpkwahc-nvDGDYAC8nphisNqu
Redirected to https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?
openid.assoc_handle=AOQobUde_9BUnQsk91rb_Sf9tguJ-S7Gpkwahc-nvDGDYAC8nphisNqu

&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request
&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select
&openid.mode=checkid_setup
&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0
&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0
&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1
&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fuser_session%3Ffor_session%3D1%26_method%3Dpost%26open_id_complete%3D1

Completed in 2708ms (DB: 15) | 302 Found [http://localhost/user_session]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great! I got it to work!! :) Thanks to a commit by [mreinsch](http://github.com/mreinsch/authlogic_openid/commit/4a1f644be36aec75ae2d35121904b5a846354233).

Here is the URL, For anyone who wants to have auto-registration enabled:
This example app is forked from @holden example app. It does not support the Facebook oid yet. Once the bug is fixed i shall update my repo.

**Source:** http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example/tree/master

**Live Example**: http://testingauth.heroku.com/